# Find the index labels of rows that satisfies an if condition in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to drop all the rows if the value of a string in a column begins with @ or Account.

I used list comprehension and .index method but the list is not a index number.

I need index numbers of all rows to be dropped.

```py
x = [
    i.index for i in df['Cleared/Open Items Symbol'] 
    if isinstance(i, str) if i.startswith('@') or i.startswith('Account')
]
 
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.contains`. This is part of `pandas`. By default it checks regular expressions. It will return `True` or `False`, i.e. type bool for all rows. As you want to drop those you negate it with the tilde operator and take the according elements from your dataframe. This can be written in a simple one-liner.

```
dfnew = df[~df['columnName'].str.contains('^@|^Account')]
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what the parts of your code do. This should include regular expressions, the use of the tilde operator etc.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I assume that OP has done some work on pandas and should be able to comprehend basic code. For other people who have no experience in pandas, your edit helps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's the idea. My pleasure (learned something myself). Cheers